# Kinit Inside a python console not working

Tags: python, kerberos, pyodbc

I am trying to use kinit method inside a Python console and its not working. This is what I am trying in the macOS terminal. I've already generated the Keytab file

```
kinit ABC@XXXX.ORG -k -t xyz.keytab
```

and then invoke the python command line and then try to execute the pyodbc command

```
db2=pyodbc.connect(r'driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=host1;database=test_Datamart;trusted_conection=yes;')
```

When I just give the sqlcmd thing on terminal I was able to connect to sqlserver

```
sqlcmd -S xxxx.org,5432 -E -d test_Datamart
```

but when I invoke the python and try to connect using pyodbc, its throwing an error.

```
 pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Any suggestions please??

Comment: You could fix the typo in `trusted_conection`, to begin with...

Comment: Does the kinit work outside python? Is the KDC supplied-by Microsoft Active-Directory?

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the single quotes to double quotes worked for me!

```
db2=pyodbc.connect"driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=host1;database=test_Datamart;trusted_conection=yes;")
```